# Would Super Dragon Ball grant these wish?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In dragon ball super, the super shenron can grant any wish with no limitation and much more powerful than reguler shenron. But, I wonder if he can grant wish if for example someone want to be more powerful than zeno, or any other too big wish. What do you think?

Comment: Zero cannot be considered "strong" as in the usual sense, e.g. when we're talking about Goku, Beerus or Whis. I doubt he has any physical strength. He just has complete control over anythig really, being able to just erase anyone or even a whole universe.

Answer (score 2):

Dragon Balls can't grant wishes that are more powerful than their creators (Link about Shenron and Porunga stating this but it applies to all Dragon Ball dragons)

http://ultradragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Shenron

http://ultradragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Porunga

And in Dragon Ball Super it is stated than nobody is more poweful than Zeno, so no, he couldnt grant a wish to be more powerful than Zeno

"Zen-Oh is the most powerful character in the entire Dragon Ball franchise"

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Zen-Oh

Comment: Not counting Tori-bot of course.

Comment: I dont know, open another topic for that question. Tori-bot doesnt even exist in the Dragon Ball movies, Dragon Ball Heroes or Dragon Ball GT which werent authored by Toriyama so the tag of most powerful character in the entire DB franchise is debatable. And in Dragon Ball Super as far as I know, he hasnt appeared. Broly wasnt created by Toriyama but there you have Kale based in Broly so I wouldnt argue DBS is completely authored by Toriyama

Comment: correction* aparently an image of him appears in Dragon Ball GT in a razor

Comment: Some people argues than since he's the author, he could erase with a pencil any character. But he wasnt the author of (again) Dragon Ball Heroes, the Dragon Ball Movies from the 90's, Dragon Ball GT, etc. And Toei owns the anime and Shueisha owns the manga so they could erase anyone they want